# c3js - change the initial date label in x-axis

Tags: d3.js, javascript, c3.js

I have a c3js line graph of type [`timeseries`](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html).

My axis tables are currently like this:

[image: Showing the x-axis]
`11/10.....05/11.....11/11.....05/12.....11/12.....05/13.....11/13`

and it want it to be

`.12/10.....06/11.....12/11.....06/12.....12/12.....06/13.....`

where each dot indicates a month, note that the datapoint at 11/10 is still kept and displayed, only the axis labelling has changed. FYI, The increment is not set directly but hacked using `culling`.

Is there any way to alter the starting label to `12/10` (with all subsequent labels increasing in 6-months intervals)?

**UPDATE (14NOV14): I have added a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9kpx3r/1/) for you to tinker with. Any help is appreciated!**
**UPDATE (14NOV14): I have tried [using functions](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9kpx3r/2/) for this. But I want the 'pop-up' box to show the grey heading all the time.**

Comment: can you put a plunkr together to understand what you are doing better?

Comment: @Sebastian Plu - I'm trying to make one...but not so much luck - http://plnkr.co/edit/yASPgG76uA7WDsZz2Au4?p=preview
 and 
http://jsfiddle.net/ew9kpx3r/

Comment: @Sebastian Plu - If you look at http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html, the equivalent to what I want is for the x-axis to only start labelling the axis at '2013-01-02', and have a label every 2 days. So it will miss out '2013-01-01', '2013-01-03'... even though the data point is still there.

Comment: do you have it in jsfiddle with the culling hack?

Comment: @anoop Culling isn't a hack I want to follow, since if the client adds a different/new date I'm minced meat. Please see my latest jsFiddle (in the update). Thanks for your interest and help!

Comment: @dayuloli Great. Just added an else part :D ... http://jsfiddle.net/anupvarghese/ew9kpx3r/4/

Comment: @anoop, thanks for you interest in this! I've been scratching my head for 2 days!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a painfully long learning process, for a very badly-documented library. But I had to use a function for the format option for the tick, and then format the title again for the tooltip. Here's the [final, working copy](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9kpx3r/3/).

**HTML (Include the [`d3.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.min.js), [`c3.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.min.js), and [`c3.css`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.min.css) scripts too)**

```
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chartContainer',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-04-01', '2013-05-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-07-04', '2013-08-05', '2013-09-06'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: function (x) {
                    if((x.getMonth()+1) % 6 === 0) {
                        return ('0' + (x.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + x.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            title: function (d) {
                var format = d3.time.format('%m/%y');
                return format(d)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**N.B. Also be aware that `culling` might interfere with this. I had to set `culling: {max: 100}` to ensure any built in incrementations are not applied.**